# JQuery Mobile page <head> content not changing after new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, joomla3.0

If I go to a page on my site that has JQuery mobile loaded (1.4.5) and then transition to another page (e.g. clicking on a link like `<a href="/">Home</a>`) it only loads the `<body>...</body>` part of the new page.

The `<head>...</head>` content appears to be unchanged and this is causing a lot of pain with missing js libs, css files etc.
Requesting a page fresh from the browser fixes the problem as the correct header is then loaded.

I'm working with Joomla 3.4 as the CMS but after much investigation I doubt this is a Joomla issue. It happens regardless of the template I use and other JS frameworks loaded. I've include JQuery noconflict, using `JHtml::_('jquery.framework')`, with no change in behaviour.

So I'm now wondering if JQuery Mobile enforces some sort of header caching?

Comment: This is the normal behavior of jQM. When Ajax navigation is activated (default) only content of `body` is changed, the rest of the page is kept untouched. If you want to load pages with new `head`, disable Ajax globally or just add `data-ajax="false"` or `data-rel="external"` to anchor.

Comment: Thank you so much Omar! That led me to adding into my jquery-noconflict.js file, which loads after jQ but before jQM, the line jQuery(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    jQuery.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
}); Now my pages load perfectly.